# How to update an existing csv file with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have to check in a csv file if data exist, if they don't exist I have to add them in the existing B.csv file.

I know that the names of the columns are different in the source csv file and the destination csv file. Then, I also know that

1. the data of the columns "Jobstream" and "Job description" of the file A.csv correspond respectively with the data of the columns "Name" and "Documentation" of the file B.csv.
2. if they match, I do nothing in the B.csv file.
3. If they don't match, I add to the file B.csv in the column "Name" the value of "Jobstream" and in the column "Documentation" the value of "Job description" and finally I increment the last value of the column ID which is for example b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49344 to assign it to the new inserted line.  I'm not sure how to do this. Please, can you help me?

I have this script which is certainly not up to scratch and takes a long time to finish

```
function CompareTwoColumnsOfTwoCsv{

    $oldElementsCsv = Import-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Archi\B.csv -Delimiter ','
    #get Jobstream in A.csv
    $NewExtract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925Jobstream = Import-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Archi\A.csv -Delimiter ','
    #Output progress:
    $output= @()
    ForEach ( $row in $NewExtract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925Jobstream){

        $objMatch = $oldElementsCsv | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne $row.Jobstream}

        if($objMatch){

            $output += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID="N/A"; Type="N/A"; Name= $row.Jobstream; Documentation= $row."Job Description"}

            Write-Warning "Found new Jobstream : $($row."Jobstream")"
            Write-Warning "Found new Jobstream Description : $($row."Job Description")"
        }else {
            $output += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID= $_.ID; Type=$_Type; Name= $_Name; Documentation= $_.Documentation}
            Write-Warning "Found same value  for Name and  Jobstream  columns: $($_Name)"
            Write-Warning "Found same value for  new Jobstream Description and docuemnt columns: $($_.Documentation)"
        }
    }
    $output | Export-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Archi\B.csv" -Force -Append -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 


    #open new File:
    notepad $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Archi\B.csv

}
CompareTwoColumnsOfTwoCsv
```

**B.csv**

```
ID,"Type","Name","Documentation"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49206,"TechnologyService","BDDO401H-040D","Export"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49207,"TechnologyService","BDDO401H-041T","Transfert de Dump"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49208,"TechnologyService","BDDO401H-042D","Suppression des Objets"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49209,"TechnologyService","BDDO401H-043D","Import dataDump"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49210,"TechnologyService","BDDO401H-050M","Arret de Base REFE"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49211,"TechnologyService","BDDO401H-051M","Demarrage de Base REFE"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49212,"TechnologyService","BDDO900H-005S","Lancement sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49213,"TechnologyService","BDDO952Q-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49214,"TechnologyService","BDDO954H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49215,"TechnologyService","BDDO956H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49216,"TechnologyService","BDDO956Q-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49217,"TechnologyService","BDDO958H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49218,"TechnologyService","BDDO960H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49219,"TechnologyService","BDDO962Q-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49220,"TechnologyService","BDDO964H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49221,"TechnologyService","BDDO966H-005S",""
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49222,"TechnologyService","BDDO968Q-005S","Lancement sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49223,"TechnologyService","BDDO970H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49224,"TechnologyService","BDDO972H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49225,"TechnologyService","BDDO974Q-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49226,"TechnologyService","BDDO976H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49227,"TechnologyService","BDDO978H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49228,"TechnologyService","BDDO980Q-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49229,"TechnologyService","BDDO982H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49230,"TechnologyService","BDDO984H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49231,"TechnologyService","BDDO986Q-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49232,"TechnologyService","BDDO988H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49233,"TechnologyService","BDDO990H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49234,"TechnologyService","BDDO992Q-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49235,"TechnologyService","BDDO994H-005S","Lancement Sauvegarde"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49236,"TechnologyService","BDDO996H-005S",""
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49237,"TechnologyService","BISI160Q-005S","BCKP FULL"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49238,"TechnologyService","BISI162Q-007S","sauvegarde incrementale"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49239,"TechnologyService","BISI164Q-008S","BCK LOG BISI"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49240,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-060T","Extract Sinistres_SUSI"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49241,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-070T","Push Sinistres_SUSI file"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49242,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-080T","UDM BISI001"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49243,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-090T","Get Sinistres_SUSI"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49244,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-100T","w_AlimODSWBXL"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49245,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-110T","w_AlimODSWBXL_SUSI"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49246,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-130T","w_BUS_REF15_DWH"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49247,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-140T","w_CONT_ChargeDimensions"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49248,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-150T","Push calendar file"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49249,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-151T","UDM BISI003"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49250,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-152T",""
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49251,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-160T","w_DWH_SINI_ChargeCalendr"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49252,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-170T","w_SINI_TraitementQuotid"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49253,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-180T","w_SINI_TraitementCloture"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49254,"TechnologyService","BISI211Q-190T","Process Cube"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49255,"TechnologyService","BISI300H-000M","REBOOT Server"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49256,"TechnologyService","BISI300H-005M",""
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49257,"TechnologyService","BTRE996Q-005S","Sauv Serveur SQL IS"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49258,"TechnologyService","BTRE998Q-005S","Sauv Serveur SQL IS"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49259,"TechnologyService","CLAI020D-000M","Rstrt EXS SVC on demand"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49260,"TechnologyService","CLAI110Q-110S","Bck sys-xxAXCCLAIMBDD01"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49261,"TechnologyService","CLAI130H-000T","Run Query + Mail + Arch"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49262,"TechnologyService","CLAI150H-110S","bck full prod claims"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49263,"TechnologyService","CLAI160Q-110S","Bck diff claims bdd"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49264,"TechnologyService","CLAI170Q-110S",""
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49265,"TechnologyService","CLAI200Q-000T","Script PowerShell"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49266,"TechnologyService","CLAI210Q-310S","Bck sys-xxAXCCLAIMAPP01"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49267,"TechnologyService","CLAI333M-303M","RESTART SRV APPLI CLAIMS"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49268,"TechnologyService","CLAI333M-331M","RESTART SRV BDD CL"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49269,"TechnologyService","CLOT100D-005T","Supp. Droits Folder"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49270,"TechnologyService","CLOT100D-010T","Histo / Copy  Fic. INPUT"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49271,"TechnologyService","CLOT100D-015T","Workflows INFORMATICA"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49272,"TechnologyService","CLOT100D-020T","Histo / Copy Fic. OUTPUT"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49273,"TechnologyService","CLOT100D-025T","Attrib. Droits Folder"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49274,"TechnologyService","CLOT110D-005T","Supp. Droits Folder"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49275,"TechnologyService","CLOT110D-010T","Histo / Copy  Fic. INPUT"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49276,"TechnologyService","CLOT110D-015T","Workflows INFORMATICA"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49277,"TechnologyService","CLOT110D-020T","Histo / Copy Fic. OUTPUT"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49278,"TechnologyService","CLOT110D-025T","Attrib. Droits Folder"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49279,"TechnologyService","CLOT180D-005T","recheck and lock folder"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49280,"TechnologyService","CLOT180D-010T","move in_files 2 UDM src"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49281,"TechnologyService","CLOT180D-015T","UDM CLOT180 - USR 2 ETL"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49282,"TechnologyService","CLOT180D-020T","move in file to ETL"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49283,"TechnologyService","CLOT180D-025T","Start workflows"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49284,"TechnologyService","CLOT180D-030T","move out_file to UDM src"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49285,"TechnologyService","CLOT180D-040T","UDM CLOT182 - ETL 2 USR"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49286,"TechnologyService","CLOT180D-045T","move UDM file 2 user tgt"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49287,"TechnologyService","CLOT180D-055T","Unlock usr folder"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49288,"TechnologyService","CLOT181D-010I","Merge logs"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49289,"TechnologyService","CLOT181D-015T","UDM CLOT181 logs 4 USR"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49290,"TechnologyService","CLOT190D-005T","recheck and lock folder"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49291,"TechnologyService","CLOT190D-010T","move in_files 2 UDM src"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49292,"TechnologyService","CLOT190D-015T","UDM CLOT190 - USR 2 ETL"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49293,"TechnologyService","CLOT190D-020T","move in file to ETL"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49294,"TechnologyService","CLOT190D-025T","Start workflows"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49295,"TechnologyService","CLOT190D-030T","move out_file to UDM src"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49296,"TechnologyService","CLOT190D-040T","UDM CLOT192 - ETL 2 USR"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49297,"TechnologyService","CLOT190D-045T","move UDM file 2 user tgt"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49298,"TechnologyService","CLOT190D-055T","Unlock usr folder"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49299,"TechnologyService","CLOT191D-010I","Merge logs"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49300,"TechnologyService","CLOT191D-015T","UDM CLOT191 logs 4 USR"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49301,"TechnologyService","COGN100H-005M","RBT-SRVBDD01"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49302,"TechnologyService","COGN120D-005T","Move fic. pour transfert"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49303,"TechnologyService","COGN120D-010T","Transfert UDM xCOGN003"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49304,"TechnologyService","COGN120D-020T","Move Fic to User"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49305,"TechnologyService","COGN130D-010T","Tranfert UDM (PCOGN004)"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49306,"TechnologyService","COGN130D-020T","Archivage Package"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49307,"TechnologyService","COGN130D-030T","Transfert UDM (PCOGN005)"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49308,"TechnologyService","COGN130D-040T","Move Fic. + Envoi mail"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49319,"TechnologyService","COGN300H-000T","ArrÃªt service COGNOS"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49320,"TechnologyService","COGN300H-010T","REBOOT du server"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49324,"TechnologyService","DWHS211Q-070T","Get Taux file from Matfi"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49325,"TechnologyService","DWHS211Q-080T","Push taux to UDM001"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49326,"TechnologyService","DWHS211Q-085T","UDM001 matfic -> ETL"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49327,"TechnologyService","DWHS211Q-090T","Get Taux from UDM001"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49328,"TechnologyService","DWHS211Q-100T","w_06_BUS_CMPT_REF0"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49329,"TechnologyService","DWHS211Q-110T","w_08_BUS_REF0_DWH"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49330,"TechnologyService","DWHS211Q-120T","w_AlimODSWBXL"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49331,"TechnologyService","DWHS211Q-130T","w_Ctrl"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49332,"TechnologyService","DWHS211Q-140T","w_AlimODSWBXL_STAT"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49333,"TechnologyService","DWHS212Q-100T","AGGREGATE to UDM002"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49334,"TechnologyService","DWHS212Q-110T","UDM002 Aggregate to ETL"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49335,"TechnologyService","DWHS212Q-115T","Get Aggregate from DUM"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49336,"TechnologyService","DWHS212Q-120T","w_STAT_ChargeDimension"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49337,"TechnologyService","DWHS212Q-130T","w_CONT_ChargeDimensions"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49338,"TechnologyService","DWHS212Q-140T","w_STAT_F_ACCOUNT_PROCESS"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49339,"TechnologyService","DWHS212Q-150T","w_SINI_ChargeDimensions"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49340,"TechnologyService","DWHS212Q-160T","w_STAT_F_SUB_ACCOUNT"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49341,"TechnologyService","DWHS212Q-170T","w_CONT_ChargeFaits"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49342,"TechnologyService","DWHS212Q-180T","w_SINI_ChargeFaits"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49343,"TechnologyService","DWHS212Q-190T","w_ChargeFaits_Commission"
b57a5fff-9dd2-4cm1-9141-04c042f49344,"TechnologyService","DWHS212Q-200T","End Refresh"
```

**A.csv**

```
Jobstream,"Jobstream Description","Op num","Job","Script or expected file(s)","Server","user","location","Job Description"
COGN130D-040T,"Move Package COGNOS V11","70","PCOGN0A5","PCOGN-130D-040T.BAT","CAVAH000","PRPRIVMGMT\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+COGN-014","Move Fic. + Envoi mail"
OGN130D,"Move Package COGNOS V11","255","","technical","","","","End Of JobStream"
OGN202H,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (H)","9","","technical","","","","Begin Of JobStream"
COGN202H-005D,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (H)","40","PCOGN0BD","PCOGN-202H-005D.BAT","CAVAH000","PRPRIVMGMT\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+COGN-015","Run rapports + Zip"
COGN202H-010T,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (H)","45","PCOGN0BE","PCOGN-202H-010T.KSH","PRATFUDMGTW01","udmwkld","F+COGN-011","UDM xCOGN007"
COGN202H-012T,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (H)","47","PCOGN0BJ","PCOGN-202H-012T.BAT","PRAXCAPP02","AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+COGN-012","Unzip RPT"
COGN202H-015D,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (H)","50","PCOGN0BF","PCOGN-202H-015D.BAT","PRAXCINFTCA01","AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+COGN-008","Wkf  (wf_BUS_REPORTING)"
COGN202H-025D,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (H)","60","PCOGN0BH","PCOGN-202H-025D.BAT","PRAXCINFTCA01","AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+COGN-008","Insertion Rapports"
OGN202H,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (H)","255","","technical","","","","End Of JobStream"
OGN202Q,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (Q)","9","","technical","","","","Begin Of JobStream"
COGN202Q-005D,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (Q)","40","PCOGN0A6","PCOGN-202Q-005D.BAT","CAVAH000","PRPRIVMGMT\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+COGN-015","Run rapports + Zip"
COGN202Q-010T,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (Q)","45","PCOGN0A7","PCOGN-202Q-010T.KSH","PRATFUDMGTW01","udmwkld","F+COGN-011","UDM xCOGN008"
COGN202Q-012T,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (Q)","47","PCOGN0BK","PCOGN-202Q-012T.BAT","PRAXCAPP02","AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+COGN-012","Unzip RPT"
COGN202Q-015D,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (Q)","50","PCOGN0A8","PCOGN-202Q-015D.BAT","PRAXCINFTCA01","AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+COGN-008","Wkf  (wf_BUS_REPORTING)"
COGN202Q-025D,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (Q)","60","PCOGN0BA","PCOGN-202Q-025D.BAT","PRAXCINFTCA01","AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+COGN-008","Insertion Rapports"
OGN202Q,"Reporting ACTOR V2 (Q)","255","","technical","","","","End Of JobStream"
OGN300H,"REBOOT SRV COGNOS V11","9","","technical","","","","Begin Of JobStream"
COGN300H-000T,"REBOOT SRV COGNOS V11","40","PCOGN0BB","PCOGN-300H-000T.BAT","CAVAH000","PRPRIVMGMT\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+COGN-009","Arrï¿½t service COGNOS"
COGN300H-010T,"REBOOT SRV COGNOS V11","50","PCOGN0BC","PCOGN-300H-010T.BAT","CAVAH000","PRPRIVMGMT\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+COGN-009","REBOOT du server"
OGN300H,"REBOOT SRV COGNOS V11","255","","technical","","","","End Of JobStream"
WHS200D,"SQLLoader Fichiers CSV","9","","technical","","","","Begin Of JobStream"
DWHS200D-005T,"SQLLoader Fichiers CSV","40","PDWHS0BJ","PDWHS-200D-005T.BAT","PRAXCAPP02","AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+DWHS-004","R{cup{ration Fic. CSV"
DWHS200D-010T,"SQLLoader Fichiers CSV","45","PDWHS0BK","PDWHS-200D-010T.BAT","PRAXCINFTCA01","AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+DWHS-007","wf_AGPC_Charge_SINISTRES"
DWHS200D-020T,"SQLLoader Fichiers CSV","55","PDWHS0BM","PDWHS-200D-020T.BAT","PRAXCAPP02","AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+DWHS-004","Mise ï¿½ Dispo. Fic. Usr."
WHS200D,"SQLLoader Fichiers CSV","255","","technical","","","","End Of JobStream"
WHS211Q,"ETL DWH REFE","9","","technical","","","","Begin Of JobStream"
DWHS211Q-070T,"ETL DWH REFE","70","PDWHS0FZ","PDWHS-211Q-070T.BAT","PRAXCAPP02","AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+DWHS-004","Get Taux file from Matfi"
DWHS211Q-080T,"ETL DWH REFE","80","PDWHS0EZ","PDWHS-211Q-080T.BAT","PRAXCAPP02","AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING","F+DWHS-004","Push taux to UDM001"
DWHS211Q-085T,"ETL DWH REFE","85","PDWHS0EY","PDWHS-211Q-085T.KSH","PRATFUDMGTW01","svcudmu","F+DWHS-006","UDM001 matfic -> ETL"
DWHS211Q-090T,"ETL DWH REFE","90","PDWHS0F0","PDWHS-211Q-090T.KSH","CARAA009","svc_se_prod_dwhs01","F+DWHS-008","Get Taux from UDM001"
DWHS211Q-100T,"ETL DWH REFE","100","PDWHS0EF","PDWHS-211Q-100T.KSH","CARAA009","svc_se_prod_dwhs01","F+DWHS-008","w_06_BUS_CMPT_REF0"
DWHS211Q-110T,"ETL DWH REFE","110","PDWHS0EG","PDWHS-211Q-110T.KSH","CARAA009","svc_se_prod_dwhs01","F+DWHS-008","w_08_BUS_REF0_DWH"
DWHS211Q-120T,"ETL DWH REFE","120","PDWHS0EK","PDWHS-211Q-120T.KSH","CARAA009","svc_se_prod_dwhs01","F+DWHS-008","w_AlimODSWBXL"
DWHS211Q-130T,"ETL DWH REFE","130","PDWHS0EL","PDWHS-211Q-130T.KSH","CARAA009","svc_se_prod_dwhs01","F+DWHS-008","w_Ctrl"
DWHS211Q-140T,"ETL DWH REFE","140","PDWHS0EM","PDWHS-211Q-140T.KSH","CARAA009","svc_se_prod_dwhs01","F+DWHS-008","w_AlimODSWBXL_STAT"
WHS211Q,"ETL DWH REFE","255","","technical","","","","End Of JobStream"
WHS212Q,"Dwh Stat","9","","technical","","","","Begin Of JobStream"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish, are you just trying to append new entries to a csv from another csv with changed labels? Or are you just trying to compare the difference between two different columns of a csv? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: What exactly is `ID` in B.csv? It looks like it's pretending to be a GUID or UUID, but it's not (it has an `m` in it, for starters). What is it composed of? How many characters are used for the sequential number?

Comment: I do two things, the first is to compare two columns, thesecond, if the value does not exist I add it to the existing csv file by generating a GUID key in the ID column

Comment: Does it have to be a "sequential" GUID key, because that doesn't really make sense and it's not how they're intended to be used. It's going to be relatively difficult to manipulate that. If you need a new GUID, I'd expect you to call `[GUID]::NewGuid().GUID`.

Comment: Indeed it is not a sequential key, it is a good idea to use ID=NewGuid().GUID.

Answer (score 0):

> I propose this solution, in use by combining [GUID]:[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(), then StreamReader and StreamWriter

```
process{
    
    #Import  B.csv
    $oldElementsCsv=Import-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Archi\B.csv -Delimiter ','
    #get Jobstream in A.csv and check in present in A.csv
    $reader='.\Archi\A.csv'
    $NewExtract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925Jobstream=  New-Object IO.StreamReader ($reader)
    #Output progress:
    $path=".\Archi\A.csv"
    $writer= New-Object  System.IO.StreamWriter ($path)
    $writer.WriteLine(($NewExtract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925Jobstream.ReadLine()))
    $output= @()
    while ($null -ne ($line =$NewExtract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925Jobstream.ReadLine()) ){

            $fields=$line -split ','
                    ForEach ( $row in  $fields){

                            $objMatch = $oldElementsCsv | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne $row.Jobstream} 
            
                            if($objMatch){
                            
                                    $output += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID=[guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); Type="N/A" ; Name= $row.Jobstream; Documentation= $row."Job Description"} 
                                    
                            Write-Warning "Found new Jobstream : $($row."Jobstream")"
                            Write-Warning "Found new Jobstream Description : $($row."Job Description")"
                            $writer.WriteLine(($output -join ','))
                            #$writer.Close()
                            }else {
                                    $output += New-Object PsObject -Property @{ID= $_.ID; Type=$_Type; Name= $_Name; Documentation= $_.Documentation} 
                                    Write-Warning "Found same value  for Name and  Jobstream  columns: $($_Name)"
                                    Write-Warning "Found same value for  new Jobstream Description and Documentation columns: $($_.Documentation)"
                                    $writer.WriteLine(($output -join ','))
                                    #$writer.Close()
                            }
                    }
            
           
    }
   
    $output | Export-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Archi\B.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 
    $NewExtract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925Jobstream.Dispose()
    $NewExtract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925Jobstream.Close()
    $writer.Dispose()
    $writer.Close()
    #open new File:
    notepad $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Archi\B.csv
```

}